# java clipboard between linux and windows

Tags: java, linux, awt, clipboard

I am using the following standard java code to copy string into clipboard.

```
StringSelection ss = new StringSelection("abc");
Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard().setContents(ss, ss);
```

I run the java code on windows, and can paste into any other windows application.

What I want is to be able to run the Java code on linux server (through Putty), and still be able to paste to the Windows apps, such as Excel/Notepad. Or is there any better way to share contents (mainly text) between linux/windows using copy/paste style? (assuming copy on linux and paste on windows)

Comment: If you have a connection between two computers via a program, that program is what's handling the copy paste.  So unless you've implemented a Remote Desktop type software in Java, running code on one or the other machine won't help.

Answer (score 0):

Download a VNC client on Windows and you can run a VNC server on Linux and [copy and paste between them](https://askubuntu.com/questions/41273/how-to-copy-paste-text-from-remote-system).

Comment: Cannot install vnc server on linux box.